# AWS SDK v 2 Integration in iOS and getting error

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-s3

I am receiving the following error after integrating  AWS SDK V 2 which is downloaded from the link https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios-v2

Error thorwn in my xcode seen like below:

*AWSiOSSDKv2 [Error] AWSSerialization.m line:1486 | +[AWSJSONParser dictionaryForJsonData:actionName:serviceDefinitionRule:error:] | JSON definition File is empty or can not be found, will return un-serialized dictionary*

Samples of SDK i downloaded from the GitHub repository: github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples and when i run the app and try to upload a files the above errors are thrown.

Please help me to resolve this. However downloading a file works fine and verified in Chrome tool S3 Browser.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make sure you have followed the steps to correctly configure the SDK available here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/setup.html specifically step 7 on the service-definition files.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.

Answer (score 0):

I got it Woking by using the API which accepts access key n secret key.

Regards,
Chandrika